# Get text for element with no tags selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, gettext, child-nodes

I want to get the text 'Rejected' in below code.

```
<tr bgcolor="#f0f0f0">
    <td class="bodyText" width="45%">
    <td class="bodyText" width="55%">
        <b>Status:</b>
        Rejected                               
        <input type="checkbox" title="XYZ" disabled=""/>
         Expired                                                               
        <b>Strategy:</b>
        <a href="ABC.aspx?accountID=123456&loanAppID=891011&StrategyName="/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Text is changing and i need to validate it accordingly. How can i retrieve the text and verify.
I'm trying to add element

```
by.xpath(".//b[contains(.,'Status')]")
```

and getting child node. But don't have idea how to do that here. Can anyone please help to retrieve the text by any way?

Answer (score 1):

To 'go up' one node, with xpath, use /..

```
//b[contains(.,'Status')]/..
```

Comment: This will go to <td class="bodyText" width="55%">

Answer (score 0):

This should get you the containing element (assuming there aren't other TDs just like this one outside of the example HTML).

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("td.bodyText[width='55%']));
```

Once you get that you can do one of the following:

1. a `.getText()` and do a Regex for 'Status: X' where 'X' is what you are looking for.
2. a `.getAttribute("innerHTML")` and parse that portion of the HTML... probably using a Regex.

Comment: Thanks for the ans @JeffC, but there are other TDs also. as of now, i have directly took xpath of the element, but not a reliable thing as it is prone to change.

Comment: Please post some of the TDs outside of the area that you care about. There may be a way to exclude those.